# Mutliple sound streams with configurable volume level using ALSA lib

Tags: linux, alsa, audio

I would like to use ALSA library to play mutliple sound streams, with each stream having its own customizable volume level. Would like to avoid using higher level abstractions like pulseaudio, since this is to be used on a ARM target board with single channel output, would like to avoid compiling pulseaudio and the associated issue. Please suggest in what all possible ways such an implementation can be done. Any guidance with usage of ALSA plugins dmix / softvol is welcome

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing multiple wav files using ALSA in C with different volumes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713741/playing-multiple-wav-files-using-alsa-in-c-with-different-volumes)

Comment: Looks similar, but that is not answered either.

Comment: In what way *not answered*? There seem to be two workable solutions there.